# Why my code prints others characters? cipher

Tags: python

I want print only letters but it's prints special characters of ASCII. My code:

```
import string
def caesar(shift):
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    dict={}
    emptylist=[]
    int(shift)
    for x in alphabet:
        emptylist.append(x)
        code = ""
        for letters in emptylist:
            code = chr(ord(letters) + shift)
            dict[letters]=code
    return dict
caesar(12)
```

My output:

> 'm': 'y', 'l': 'x', 'o': '{', 'n': 'z', 'q': '}', 'p': '|', 's': '\x7f', 'r': '~', 'u': '\x81', 't': '\x80', 'w': '\x83', 'v': '\x82', 'y': '\x85', 'x': '\x84', 'z': '\x86'

Correct output:

> 'm': 'y', 'l': 'x', 'o': 'a', 'n': 'z', 'q': 'c', 'p': 'b', 's': 'e', 'r': 'd', 'u': 'g', 't': 'f', 'w': 'i', 'v': 'h', 'y': 'k', 'x': 'j', 'z': 'l'

Comment: that returns a dictionary .... neither of your expected outputs is a dictionary ...

Answer (score 5):

Using `ord()` and changing the character code won't restrict the resulting character to your dictionary.

I'd just find the index of the letter in your dictionary, shift it, and use the modulo operator:

```
import string

def caesar(shift):
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase  # <- Change it back to what you had before
                                       #    and see what will happen.
    mapping = {}

    for letter in alphabet:
        index = alphabet.index(letter)
        mapping[letter] = alphabet[(index + shift) % len(alphabet)]

    return mapping
```

Test (dictionaries don't preserve order, so it's pretty hard to read):

```
>>> caesar(12)
{'A': 'M', 'C': 'O', 'B': 'N', 'E': 'Q', 'D': 'P', 'G': 'S', 'F': 'R', 'I': 'U', 'H': 'T', 'K': 'W', 'J': 'V', 'M': 'Y', 'L': 'X', 'O': 'A', 'N': 'Z', 'Q': 'C', 'P': 'B', 'S': 'E', 'R': 'D', 'U': 'G', 'T': 'F', 'W': 'I', 'V': 'H', 'Y': 'K', 'X': 'J', 'Z': 'L'}
```

Comment: @user1609625: That's not hard to fix. Try it.

Comment: I'd use something like `if letter.islower(): mapping[letter] = mapping[letter].lower()`

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at one error in particular: `o: '{'`.

Notice that `ord('o')` is 111, so let's look at the `chr` of integers in the `range(111,130)`:

Starting at `o`, shifting by 12, takes you to the `{` character:

```
In [75]: ' '.join([chr(x) for x in range(111,130)])
Out[75]: 'o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ \x7f \x80 \x81'
          ^ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...12
```

So the reason why you are getting incorrect output is because your formula

```
code = chr(ord(letters) + shift)
```

isn't taking into account what happens if the shift bounces you out of the ords associated with `a-z` or `A-Z`. (Note that the ord ranges for `a-z` and `A-Z` are not contiguous either!)

---

Here is a hint on how to fix:

```
In [82]: alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase

In [83]: alphabet.index('o')
Out[83]: 14

In [84]: alphabet[alphabet.index('o')+12]
Out[84]: 'A'
```

but

```
In [85]: alphabet[alphabet.index('O')+12]
```

results in `IndexError: string index out of range`. That's because `len(alphabet)` is 52, and

```
In [91]: alphabet.index('O')+12
Out[91]: 52
```

Somehow we need 52 to wrap back around to 0. You can do that with the [`%` modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
In [92]: 52 % 52
Out[92]: 0
```